# Cytoscape remove style from element when an event occurs

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

When I have an element I add some border when the mouse is over in order to indicate which item is going to get clicked:

```
// cy an instance of a cytoscape object
cy.on('tap',function(event){
      var evtTarget = event.target;

      if( evtTarget === cy ){
        console.log('tap on background');
        $("#nodes").hide();
        $("#no_selected").show();
      } else {
        console.log("Display Info")
        displayInfo(evtTarget._private.data.properties);
      }
    }).on('mouseover',function(event){
      var evtTarget = event.target;

      if( evtTarget !== cy ){
        console.log("Mouse Over");
        evtTarget.style('border-width','2px').style('border-color',"#AF0000");
      }
    }).on('mouseout',function(event){
      var evtTarget = event.target;
      if( evtTarget !== cy ){
        console.log("Fired");
        evtTarget.style('border-width',null).style('border-color',null);
      }
    });
```

So what I want to achieve is when a `mouseout` event happend to remove thew border from a node. So far I cannot figure out how to do that and on the code above that does not happen. Do you have any idea how to remove a `style` property from a node or an edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case just set the `border-width` in `0px` when a `mouseout` event occurs:

```
// In your case just chain it with other `on methods`
cy.on('mouseout',function(event){
      var evtTarget = event.target;
      if( evtTarget !== cy ){
        console.log("Fired");
        evtTarget.style('border-width','0px);
      }
    });
```

As fas as I've seen you just need to reset the property values into a default value that you have set on `style` section for edge or node. 
Sometimes just setting a default value (eg. for sizes 0px is enough in order not to get shown) can acheive the desired effect to the end user.